# Excel: max() of count() with column grouping in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table fed from a MySQL view. Each returned row is basically an instantiation of "a person, with a role, at a venue, on a date". The each cell then shows count of person (lets call it person_id).

When you pivot this in excel, you get a nice table of the form:

```
        | Dates -->
--------------------------
Venue   |
   Role | -count of person-
```

This makes a lot of sense, and the end user likes this format BUT the requirement has changed to group the columns (date) into a week.

When you group them in the normal way, this count is then applied in columns as well. This is, of course, logical behaviour, but what I actually want is `max()` of the original `count()`.

So the question: Does anyone know how to have cells `count()`, but the grouping perform a `max()`?

To illustrate this, imagine the columns for a week. Then imaging the `max()` grouped as a week, giving:

Old:

```
         | M | T | W | T | F | S | S ||
---------------------------------------   .... for several weeks
Venue X  |
   Role Y| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 ||
```

New (grouped by week)

```
         | Week 1 |    ...
---------------------------
Venue X  |
   Role Y|    3   |    ...
```

Comment: What excel version do you have?

Comment: 2k7.
I have 2k13 at home.

Comment: Ps: thanks for edits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my pc, but the steps below should be broadly correct:

1. You should be able to right click on the date field on pivot table and select group.
2. Then highlight week, you may have to select year also.
3. Lastly right click on the count data you already have and expand the summarise by, and select max.

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes the whole field change to max(), not a max() of count().

Comment: Are you able to update the mysql view to do the daily count for you?

Comment: This is how I'm hacking things for this one sheet at the moment: BUT that's not ideal.
It means I have to maintain two views per sheet (daily is required also), and the other criteria for these views are often being tweaked. Also - there is the likelyhood that "week" might not be appropriate as this moves onwards... I'd rather the end user just have one sheet he can modify the day grouping into.